# Number of arrangements with identical items with a restriction on the number of slots for each item?

Tags: combinatorics

I created a question slightly modified from a simple arrangements problem with identical items, and I wanted to check to make sure if not only did I get it right, but also if I solved it in the most efficient way.

The problem is as as follows: There are 5 identical books in pile A, 2 identical books in pile B, and 1 book in pile C. None of the books in their respective piles are identical to those of the other piles  i.e. there are only 3 kinds of books. How many arrangements can be created on a shelf with 6 slots using these 8 books?

I first started by creating 5 different possibilities and writing out the number of outcomes for each, and then I added them together to get the total number of possibilities. Here's what I got:

Possibility 1: 5As, 1B = $\frac{6!}{5!} = 6$

Possibility 2: 5As, 1C = $\frac{6!}{5!} = 6$

Possibility 3: 4As, 2Bs = $\frac{6!}{4!*2!} = 15$

Possibility 4: 4As, 1B, 1C = $\frac{6!}{4!} = 30$

Possibility 5: 3As, 2Bs, 1C = $\frac{6!}{3!*2!} = 60$

And the sum of these desired possibilities is 117 arrangements.

Is this correct and was there a faster way of arriving to the answer?

NOTE: I used the Mississippi case for formulating each of the possibilities i.e. if you have repeating items in a set and you want the number of arrangements, N, we get $N = \frac{n!}{b!*c!*d!*...}$ where each thing being divided out is how many of each repeating element in the set. So if I wanted the total number of arrangements of the letters in Mississippi, it would be $N = \frac{11!}{4!*4!*2!}$ where there are 4 Ss, 4 Is, and 2 Ps.

EDIT: I have been notified that the "Mississippi case" I referenced is referred to as the "multinomial"

Comment: What you call the Mississippi case is the multinomial

Comment: @DavidRaveh Alright I'll make a note of that at the bottom

Comment: Your working out looks good. I can't think of a better way than manually creating cases as you did.

Comment: @TonyMathew I hope it's right, there's always something I mess up or overlook on these style of problems.

Comment: If you enjoy coding and are enthusiastic, you could try writing a program to enumerate the arrangements and verify your calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Your methodology is correct.

I just did the brute force computation.

```
universe = {"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"}

permutations = Union[(Take[#1, 6] & ) /@ Permutations[universe]]

Length[permutations]
```

The results:

1. The books: {"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"}
2. The permutations, taking only the first 6 books of each permutation.

```
{
{A,A,A,A,A,B},{A,A,A,A,A,C},{A,A,A,A,B,A},
{A,A,A,A,B,B},{A,A,A,A,B,C},{A,A,A,A,C,A},
{A,A,A,A,C,B},{A,A,A,B,A,A},{A,A,A,B,A,B},
{A,A,A,B,A,C},{A,A,A,B,B,A},{A,A,A,B,B,C},
{A,A,A,B,C,A},{A,A,A,B,C,B},{A,A,A,C,A,A},
{A,A,A,C,A,B},{A,A,A,C,B,A},{A,A,A,C,B,B},
{A,A,B,A,A,A},{A,A,B,A,A,B},{A,A,B,A,A,C},
{A,A,B,A,B,A},{A,A,B,A,B,C},{A,A,B,A,C,A},
{A,A,B,A,C,B},{A,A,B,B,A,A},{A,A,B,B,A,C},
{A,A,B,B,C,A},{A,A,B,C,A,A},{A,A,B,C,A,B},
{A,A,B,C,B,A},{A,A,C,A,A,A},{A,A,C,A,A,B},
{A,A,C,A,B,A},{A,A,C,A,B,B},{A,A,C,B,A,A},
{A,A,C,B,A,B},{A,A,C,B,B,A},{A,B,A,A,A,A},
{A,B,A,A,A,B},{A,B,A,A,A,C},{A,B,A,A,B,A},
{A,B,A,A,B,C},{A,B,A,A,C,A},{A,B,A,A,C,B},
{A,B,A,B,A,A},{A,B,A,B,A,C},{A,B,A,B,C,A},
{A,B,A,C,A,A},{A,B,A,C,A,B},{A,B,A,C,B,A},
{A,B,B,A,A,A},{A,B,B,A,A,C},{A,B,B,A,C,A},
{A,B,B,C,A,A},{A,B,C,A,A,A},{A,B,C,A,A,B},
{A,B,C,A,B,A},{A,B,C,B,A,A},{A,C,A,A,A,A},
{A,C,A,A,A,B},{A,C,A,A,B,A},{A,C,A,A,B,B},
{A,C,A,B,A,A},{A,C,A,B,A,B},{A,C,A,B,B,A},
{A,C,B,A,A,A},{A,C,B,A,A,B},{A,C,B,A,B,A},
{A,C,B,B,A,A},{B,A,A,A,A,A},{B,A,A,A,A,B},
{B,A,A,A,A,C},{B,A,A,A,B,A},{B,A,A,A,B,C},
{B,A,A,A,C,A},{B,A,A,A,C,B},{B,A,A,B,A,A},
{B,A,A,B,A,C},{B,A,A,B,C,A},{B,A,A,C,A,A},
{B,A,A,C,A,B},{B,A,A,C,B,A},{B,A,B,A,A,A},
{B,A,B,A,A,C},{B,A,B,A,C,A},{B,A,B,C,A,A},
{B,A,C,A,A,A},{B,A,C,A,A,B},{B,A,C,A,B,A},
{B,A,C,B,A,A},{B,B,A,A,A,A},{B,B,A,A,A,C},
{B,B,A,A,C,A},{B,B,A,C,A,A},{B,B,C,A,A,A},
{B,C,A,A,A,A},{B,C,A,A,A,B},{B,C,A,A,B,A},
{B,C,A,B,A,A},{B,C,B,A,A,A},{C,A,A,A,A,A},
{C,A,A,A,A,B},{C,A,A,A,B,A},{C,A,A,A,B,B},
{C,A,A,B,A,A},{C,A,A,B,A,B},{C,A,A,B,B,A},
{C,A,B,A,A,A},{C,A,B,A,A,B},{C,A,B,A,B,A},
{C,A,B,B,A,A},{C,B,A,A,A,A},{C,B,A,A,A,B},
{C,B,A,A,B,A},{C,B,A,B,A,A},{C,B,B,A,A,A}
}
```

3. 117

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).